# Hide/Show Bottom Navigation and Collapsible Toolbar on scroll in fragment

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement show/hide behavior of bottom navigation and collapsible toolbar from a specific fragment of bottom navigation.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_200">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Parallax Area"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Currently when I scroll, only 'Parallax Area (pink)' is showing/hiding but not bottom navigation in sync. When I remove the '@+id/text_header' then my bottom navigation also shows/hides. I want to do it for only this fragment, not for the others. I came across with nested coordinator layout implementations, none of them worked.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to show/hide the `BottomNavigation` in an `Activity` when scrolling a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`.
The core idea is to set `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior`
programmatically when you're navigating Fragments

1. First of all, if you're using Navigation component from Jetpack, use `addOnDestinationChangedListener` in the Activity witch holds the nav host to get the current showing Fragment.

```kotlin
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    when (destination.id) {
        R.id.scrollToHideFragment -> {
            toggleBottomNavBehavior(true)
        }
        else -> {
            toggleBottomNavBehavior(false)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, `toggleBottomNavBehavior` will be called when the destination has changed.

2. Add `toggleBottomNavBehavior` method in the Activity

```kotlin
private fun toggleBottomNavBehavior(scrollToHide: Boolean) {
    // Get the layout params of your BottomNavigation
    val layoutParams = binding.bottomNav.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

    // Apply LayoutBehavior to the layout params
    layoutParams.behavior =
            if (scrollToHide) HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior<CoordinatorLayout>() else null

    // Add margin to Nav Host Fragment if the layout behavior is NOT added
    // bottom_nav_height is 56dp when using Material BottomNavigation
    binding.navHostMain.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            setMargins(
                0, 0, 0, if (scrollToHide) 0 else resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_nav_height)
            )
        }
    }
```

Now you can scroll in a Fragment and hide the BottomNav in the Activity!